# How can I use Digest and Basic authentications with HTTParty in the same class?

Tags: ruby, httparty

I have the following class performing some requests:

- the first request uses a digest auth
- the second request uses a basic auth

When I run the second request I have the following error:

```
only one authentication method, :basic_auth or :digest_auth may be used at a time
```

How can I invalidate the `digest_auth` prior to running the second request?

```
class Test
  include HTTParty
  debug_output $stdout
  digest_auth 'login', 'pass'

  def first_request(href)
    self.class.base_uri "SERVER:PORT"
    response = self.class.get(href, {:query => {}})
    response
  end

  def second_request(href)
    auth = {:username => "USERNAME", :password => "PASSWORD"}
    options = { :body => xml_string, :basic_auth => auth }
    response = self.class.post('', options)
    response
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use [`basic_auth`](http://rdoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/ClassMethods#basic_auth-instance_method) or [`digest_auth`](http://rdoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/ClassMethods#digest_auth-instance_method), HTTParty stores the  information internally in the `@default_options` hash. Here is the source for `basic_auth`:

```
# File 'lib/httparty.rb', line 102

def basic_auth(u, p)
  default_options[:basic_auth] = {:username => u, :password => p}
end
```

You can get access to that hash using the [`default_options`](http://rdoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/ClassMethods#default_options-instance_method) method:

```
# File 'lib/httparty.rb', line 452

def default_options #:nodoc:
  @default_options
end
```

I'd try:

```
default_options.delete(:basic_auth)
```

or:

```
default_options.delete(:digest_auth)
```

prior to using the other authentication method.

This is untested code but looks 'bout right:

```
class Test
  include HTTParty
  debug_output $stdout

  def first_request(href)
    klass = self.class
    klass.base_uri "SERVER:PORT"
    klass.default_options.delete(:basic_auth)
    klass.digest_auth 'login', 'pass'
    klass.get(href, {:query => {}})
  end

  def second_request(href)
    klass = self.class
    klass.default_options.delete(:digest_auth)
    klass.post(
      '',
      {
        :body => xml_string,
        :basic_auth => {
          :username => "USERNAME",
          :password => "PASSWORD"
        }
      }
    )
  end
end
```